# ionic 3 acces to json key

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

i can't access to a key of a json response from a restful web service.

```
{"_body":"{\"values\": {\"user_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"fred test\",\"email\":\"fred@test.test\",\"username\":\"fredtest\",\"token\":\"d5f66a06ec809d70d0c52842df8dc0011d7d1ad0f2d56f50d3123da17a2489fe\"}}","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"pragma":["no-cache"],"content-type":["text/html;charset=UTF-8"],"cache-control":["no-store"," no-cache"," must-revalidate"],"expires":["Thu"," 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"]},"type":2,"url":"http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/login"}
```

I would like to acces to 'values' in this function: (this.responseData.values)

```
login(){
console.log('login'+ this.userData);
// Your app login API web service call triggers
this.authService.postData(this.userData,'login').then((result) => {
  this.responseData = result;

  console.log('userdata : '+ temp);
  if(this.responseData.values){
    console.log('response: ' +  this.responseData);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
  }
  else{
    this.showToastWithCloseButton()
  }
}, (err) => {
  console.log('erreur : '+err);
});
```

}

I have an error undifined!

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Observable to return json data and using the subscribe function in my method and using response.json() to convert the JSON reponse from RESTful webservices.

My component method,

```
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

var response = this.service.post('deleteUserDetails/'+this.selectedUserId, null);
   response.subscribe((res) => {
   var response = res.json();
});
```

Service Post method,

```
post(url: string, data : any): Observable<any> {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
   return this.http.post(url, data,{headers: headers});
}
```

I think this might be helpful for your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for in your JSON and access the return values of your post. Something like that.

"this.responseData = result.json();" -> Return JSON. Make a for.

**Example:**

```
public postData(data, url: string) {
    this.http.post(url, data).toPromise().then(res => {
        let responseData = res.json();
        if (responseData) {
            for (var item of responseData) {            
                //Implments
            }
        }
    }, (err) => {

    });
}
```